# Combining elements in a list of list based on having common elements

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists like so

```
list=[[a], [b], [c], [d],[e],[f], [a,f], [b,c], [c,e], [b, d,f]]
```

note that it includes singles and combinations.

What I would like to do is to iterate the list  so that a new list of every possible combination of these sub-components is appended to the list of lists if and only if they share at least one common entry.

so the product is as follows

```
list2=[[a], [b], [c], [d],[e],[f], [a,f], [b,c], [c,e], [b, d,f], **[b,c,e], [a,b,d,f], [b,c,d,f], [b,c,d,e,f], [a,b,c,d,e,f]]**
```

Note the new part of the list contains the original list of lists

Comment: Ok I think I understand, but shouldn't the output list contain the combination between `[a,b,d,f]` and `[b,c]`? So shouldn't it contain `[a,b,c,d,f]`?

Comment: yes you are correct i just missed this

Comment: Where is the your code attempt which you tried?

Comment: Why [a,b,c,d,e,f]?

Comment: it is the process of making a list of nodes which are adjacent to each other which spans all possible combinations of the graph from single nodes to the entire graph.....it makes sense in terms of the application this is being created for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def similar(x):
    prev_l = 0
    while prev_l != len(x):
        to_add = []
        prev_l = len(x)
        for i in x:
            if len(i) == 1:
                continue
            for j in x:
                if len(j) == 1:
                    continue
                if any([_ in j for _ in i]) and not any([set(i+j) == set(_) for _ in x]) and not any([set(i+j) == set(_) for _ in to_add]) and i != j:
                    to_add.append(list(set(i+j)))
        x += to_add
    return x
```

Input:

```
>>> l = [['a'], ['b'], ['c'], ['d'],['e'],['f'], ['a','f'], ['b','c'], ['c','e'], ['b', 'd','f']]
>>> similar(l)
```

Output:

```
>>> l
[['a'], ['b'], ['c'], ['d'], ['e'], ['f'], ['a', 'f'], ['b', 'c'], ['c', 'e'], ['b', 'd', 'f'], ['b', 'a', 'd', 'f'], ['b', 'e', 'c'], ['b', 'd', 'c', 'f'], ['b', 'a', 'f', 'd', 'c'], ['b', 'f', 'e', 'd', 'c'], ['b', 'a', 'f', 'e', 'd', 'c']]
```

I should note this has `O(n^3)` in worst case. If you're using this for something floyd warshall I wouldn't be too worried as that has `O(n^3)` anyway, but if not you should definitely populate a distance matrix and then look for adjacency in that.